# Someone Spamming Serverfault with Noise

Tags: support, spam, spammer

Look like there is maybe someone trying out scripts that needs to be blocked:

[Leave Windows Session Logged On](https://serverfault.com/questions/103129/leave-windows-session-logged-on/141939#141939)

Noticed it since they are responses to my question. It stuff like:

"asdasdasdasd"

Comment: Flag, flag, flag. (I have done so; I can't see edit history on SF.)

Comment: Ya I flagged them.  Wasn't sure if this maybe should go on meta as well though.

Comment: It appears to be isolated to that one question, but it doesn't hurt to post here in case the problem gets worse.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's a script, just a bored user.

Any time you see noise content, flag it as such. I'd only post here on meta if it's a serious pattern warranting a lot of people's attention.

Comment: Here is where I wish I had 10K+ rep... then I could see the posts.